# how can I use wms (Web Map Service) with jquery

Tags: jquery, wms

I can using google maps in my web applications, but now I'll use wms (Web Map Service) is there any examples or links to How can using wms in jquery,now I'm seraching and looking forms on internet about Wms but I will read efficient materials about it. Or what's the Wms and how can I use it in my web application i.e: determine the way between two city

Answer (score 0):

WMS is a technique for the transfer and query of raster-based maps (that is, map images). You cannot easily do e.g. routing on a WMS layer. Depending on what you want to do, using a WMS may really be the wrong tool for the job. Essentially, if you want to do more than just display a map, a WMS will be insuficcient.

Why do you want to use a WMS?

Comment: I'm working on two technology,the first one is using wms ,second one which I'm writing using google maps,I'll use the old map's data's on google maps

Comment: Are you really sure you mean WMS, or do you mean OpenStreetMap (also known as OSM)?

Comment: til_b I'm sorry I took your time

Comment: No problem! We were all beginners once.

Comment: How can I set a wms layer to on a google maps apı v3 appliation map,is there any way to do it

Comment: According to http://www.gisdoctor.com/v3/v3_wms.html it is possible. 
Google search terms I used were "wms layer on google maps api".